# Sync Adapter perform sync not called on low internal storage

Tags: android, performance, synchronization, adapter, android-syncadapter

Have a sync adapter implementation to sync data from server to app.

It works fine when there is more than 1 GB internal storage.

But if storage is less than 1 GB, Sync Adapter's perform sync is not getting called.

Is there a minimum storage space required to have sync working ?

How to handle this case and show proper error message to user ?

Comment: *But if storage is less than 1 GB, Sync Adapter's perform sync is not getting called* **and how did you get to this assumption?** AFAIK there is no *minimum storage space required to have sync working*

Comment: Yes nothing has been mentioned in documentation regarding minimum storage space required to sync. Tried this with storage space of around 100 MB, 400MB it was not working. Then made free space up to 1GB then perform sync started getting called. Also, found Gmail also doesn't sync in this scenario, but shows warning message of low on storage. On what minimum storage condition they show this? Any idea?

Comment: Posted an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63149256/2102114